# Blank page issue in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

When i trying to navigate one page to other by using  $state.go('app.home'); shows blank page.i think the reason behind the problem is code to break while Angular is initialising the app and it ends up not being able to display the template for the first view, so the screen just displays an empty page.How to solve this problem?

my detail.js

```
$scope.submitOrder = function (datetimeValue, order_desc) {

                        var flag = true;
            var error_msg = "";
            if (service_id == 0 && flag) {

                error_msg = '<p dir="rtl">testmessage</p>';
                flag = false;
            }
            if ($scope.address == '' && flag) {

                error_msg = '<p dir="rtl">testmessage</p>';
                flag = false;
            }
            if (datetimeValue == '' && flag) {
                error_msg = '<p dir="rtl">testmessage</p>';
                flag = false;
            }



            if (!flag) {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'testmessage'
                    , template: error_msg
                    , okText: 'agree'
                });
            }


            if (flag) {
                var link = "http://test/myapp/" + "cusOrder.php";
                upload();
                if ($scope.pictureUrl.length + 1 < 5) {

                    while ($scope.pictureUrl.length < 5) {
                        $scope.pictureUrl.push("");
                    }

                }
                $http.post(link, {
                    order_date: datetimeValue
                    , cust_id: custId
                    , ser_id: service_id
                    , problem_desc: order_desc
                    , loc_x: $scope.poslat
                    , loc_y: $scope.poslng
                    , loc_name: $scope.address
                    , picture_url: $scope.pictureUrl
                }).then(function (res) {

                    if (res.data['data'] == 0) {
                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'testmessage'
                            , template: '<p dir="rtl">success</p>'
                            , okText: 'agree'
                        });

                        service_id=0;


                        $state.go('app.home');


                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    //$state.go('offlineNetwork',{obj:{PageName:'newclient'}});
                });
                $scope.pictureUrl = [];
            }
            //$scope.pictureUrl 
            //should call the upload function here 
        };
```

my app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('').previousTitleText('');
  $stateProvider
 .state('app', {
   url: "/app",
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
   controller: 'AppCtrl'
 })
 .state('app.detail', {
     url: "/detail",
     views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/detail.html",
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
   .state('app.contact', {
    url: "/contact",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
      }
    }
  })
   .state('app.payment', {
    url: "/payment",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/payment.html"
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.cart_detail', {
    url: "/cart_detail",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/cart_detail.html"
      }
    }
  })
   .state('app.about', {
    url: "/about",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
      }
    }
  })
  .state('slide', {
    url: "/slide",
    templateUrl: "templates/slide.html"
  })
   .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'

    })
 .state('register', {
      url: '/register',
      templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
      controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })

//start r@khi

 .state('app.paymentnotification', {
    url: "/paymentnotification",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/paymentnotification.html",
             controller: 'PaymentCtrl'  
            }
    }
  })

  .state('verification', {
    url: "/verification",
 views: {
      '': {
    templateUrl: "templates/verification.html",
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
}
}
  })

 .state('paymentsecurity', {
    url: "/paymentsecurity",
    templateUrl: "templates/paymentsecurity.html",
        controller: 'OrderpaymentCtrl'


  })


    .state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->


    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="lib/ion-datetime-picker/release/ion-datetime-picker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/ion-datetime-picker/release/ion-datetime-picker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/File.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugins/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer/www/FileTransfer.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script> -->
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/registerCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slideCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/detailCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/homeCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/verificationCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/paymentCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/orderpaymentCtrl.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="testapp">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: Also, Can you check your console to see if it throws any error(s)?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: how to solve this.after submiting my order i want to go home page.it work perfectly in browser.when i test in android device it shows blank page.

Comment: Can you please post your router code too?

Comment: u mean index.html?

Comment: Do you use modules like `ngRoute` (or) `ui-router` in your app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124798/discussion-between-albert-and-david-r).

Comment: anyone can help me?blank page issue again and again shown in my app